# JS Breaks when user inputs a single quote

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page with a `<div></div>` and a `<p></p>` and inside the `<p></p>` there is text with mark tags. I want to remove those mark tags and I have a function to do it.

An example of the page:

```
<div id="NoteHolder">
        <p class="NoteOp">This breaks with single quotes such as in <mark class="YelColBox" style="font-weight: bold;">didn't</mark></p>
</div>
```

The JS function to remove the mark is:

```
function removeMark(tagName, Color) {
  var notes = document.getElementsByClassName("NoteOp");
  for (var i = 0; i < notes.length; i++) {
     var n = notes[i];
     if(window.Bold === "No") {
        n.innerHTML = n.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp('<mark class="' + Color +'">(' + tagName + ')</mark>', "gim"), "$1");
     }
     if(window.Bold === "Yes") {
        n.innerHTML = n.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp('<mark class="' + Color +'" style="font-weight: bold;">(' + tagName +')</mark>', "gim"), "$1");
     }
  }
}
```

`tagName` is `didn't` and `Color` is `YelColBox`. The error I get with this is 
`Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list     test.html:1`

This makes no sense because the code on the first line of test.html is `<!DOCTYPE html>`

How would I fix this error?

Comment: can you show the line where you're calling the method?

Comment: i think the better approach is add *YelColBox* a unique class, use javascript `className` to add class. `textContent` to change the text

Comment: @kiro112 I cannot use textContent because it removes all tags inside and it will remove all of the other mark tags.

Comment: The problem isn't happening in the `removeMark` function. The problem is in the place where you're calling it, you need to escape the quote there.

Comment: You have code that looks like `removeMark('didn't', 'YelColBox')`. It needs to be either `removeMark('didn\'t', 'YelColBox')` or `removeMark("didn't" 'YelColBox')`

Comment: The place button to run the function is this: `<button id="MarkIDdidn't" onclick="removeMark ('didn't', 'YelColBox')">didn't&nbsp;<div class="YelColBox ColorBox"></div></button>`

Comment: Please post the relevant code.

Comment: Replaces `'` with `\'`: var SR = SRO.replace(new RegExp("'", "gim"), "\'"); (SRO is the input). Adds the replace function into the button that will be added to a div: `MarkListAdd.setAttribute("onclick","removeMark ('" + TagText + "','"  + ColorOptionReady + "')");` (TagText is input and ColorOptionReady is YelColBox)

Answer (score 0):

Use `&#39;` in your HTML in place of the single quote in the word didn't.

Comment: Is the user, not the coder, who would enter words containing single quotes. "JS Breaks when **user inputs** a single quote". So **removeMark** must intercept single quotes before proceeding, or coder prohibit the entering of them, maybe encoding?

Comment: @statosdotcom - the example has it embedded directly in the HTML.

Comment: Thank you and sorry: you are right, but I think this was the way Hawkeye **saw** to exemplify to us... Cheers

Comment: Yes, if the example is just for illustration and the content is user entered, then this solution may not help.

Comment: Anyway you was kind trying to help. This is important.

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove the `mark` element later after it renders into the dom.

Then in your function go like this:

```
function removeMark(tagName, Color) {
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('mark');
    while(elements.length > 0){
        elements[0].parentNode.insertBefore(elements[0].innerHTML, elements[0])
        elements[0].parentNode.removeChild(elements[0]);
    }
}
```

See if this works.

Comment: He wants to leave the contents of the `<mark>` element, he just wants to remove the tag.

Comment: @Barmar: Updated the code. You think that will work?

Comment: See my comment on the question: the syntax error is in the caller, it has nothing to do with the `removeMark` definition.